# Buttons not taking up full space

Tags: wpf, grid, controls

I have a dynamic grid that adjusts based on rows and columns size supplied. However, I can't seem to get the buttons spaced out correctly/take up all the space of the grid even though in the XAML i've set it to do some.

This is what it looks like so far:
[image] 
The lines of code for setting the height/width and orientation are:

```
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.Name = "button" + i.ToString();
        button.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        button.Padding = new Thickness(2);
        var potentialHeight = (wellGrid.Height / wellGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count) - (button.Margin.Top * 2);
        var potentialWidth = (wellGrid.Width / wellGrid.RowDefinitions.Count) - (button.Margin.Left * 2);
        button.Height = button.Width = (potentialHeight < potentialWidth) ? potentialHeight : potentialWidth;
```

The XAML is this:

```
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="wellGrid" Grid.Row="1" Width="800" Height="550"
                  local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                  local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}">
                </Grid>
```

Additional code to aid answering...

```
                int i = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; ++row)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; ++column)
                    {
                        i++;
                        grid.Children.Add(CreateGridButton(i, column, row));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to Change

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

to

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

`auto` means size to column content

`*` means size proportional to grid

this here will not help you completely, however if you want to achieve that behavior then you have 2 options here (I'm sure there are more options)

- use [UniformGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid)

  here is an example

```
<UniformGrid Rows="{Binding YOUR_ROW_COUNT}"
             Columns="{Binding YOUR_COL_COUNT}">
</UniformGrid>
```

- add **column** and **row** to your grid after adding a control

```
var length = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
var col = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = length };
var row = new RowDefinition() { Height= length };

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
```

and then after that you have to add you control like this

```
//example
Grid.SetRow(control, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(control, 2);
```

Comment: Changing to Unique Grid breaks the code... will try the other option...

Comment: not sure how i can get the second option working... i don't know what to change in code... i've added more code to help

Comment: @slickchick2 it works perfectly with UniformGrid I just tested it. you don't need any extra GridHelper there, just replace your Grid with UniformGrid and add your control there. And if you want to have them filled up then remove your Col and Row Bindings.

Comment: oh wow you're a complete legend! Sorry i was being a pleb and still had my local:gridhelper.columncount instead of Rows/Columns for the unique grid. Awesome!!!! I wonder what the difference between unique grid and grid really is :\

Comment: @slickchick2 uniformgrid is just another panel that "automatically" generates the cols and rows for you. tip: if you want to know how are these things programmed then look at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/UniformGrid.cs,a4592db73e6521dc